# How to demonstrate if two class has both association and dependency relationship on UML class diagram?

Tags: class, dependencies, uml, associations

Let A and B are classes. A is associated with B and A also uses some static methods of B, so there is both association and dependency relationship from A to B.

How should this relationship be demonstrated on UML class diagram? Should I use 2 arrows between those classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two association lines, but that's not necessary. You would usually denote that with association role names and the dot-notation. So this notation

[image]

is representing the same as this one:

[image]

Or in the double association representation:

[image]